# can anyone explain to me what is the difference between a window and a frame in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Most often in Selenium, I come across the topics in selenium handling windows and handling frames. Can anyone explain to me clearly what is the difference between handling a frame and handling a window in selenium? I am new to selenium.

Comment: provide more info: 1. Have you tried handling a window or a frame? 2. What worked for you? Show code. 3. Where are you stuck? 4. What is error you are seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Frame** is used in selenium to select a particular frame form HTML source. 
Suppose, some HTML elements are present inside an iframe of HTML source, therefore you are not able to take event on those elements until to use selectFrame API.

**Example :** `selenium.selectFrame("widget0");`

**Window** will be used in those cases where after take some event a new browser popup window open 
and you need to take action on the popup window instead of main browser page. 
After doing your operation you need to select back your main browser window.

**Example :** `selenium.selectWindow("name=widget0");`

Hope it will help you.